# React clears state on window.confirm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple state to store the files uploaded
`const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);`

When I submit/create the form it uploads normally,
The issue is when I try to save to draft, it puts the `files` to initial state.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (halfFilledForm) {
  const unblock = history.block((_) => {
    if (window.confirm("Do you want to save the Story Idea as Draft?")) {
       console.log(files) // prints to `[]`
       saveAsDraft();
    }
    return true;
  });
  return () => {
    unblock();
  };
}}, [halfFilledForm]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to pass `files` as dependency to `useEffect` hook